# Linux video capture does not work cam3 or Image capture in cam1 fails

Tags: kernel, drivers, usb, camera, v4l

I am trying to some solution or run-time fix on this.

Problem:
    After connecting a 3rd camera, Linux video capture does not work cam3 or Image capture in cam1 fails.

History:
    Initially, we developed a system for surveillance. The system comprised of 2 cameras.

```
1. Video capture (Using Motion)
2. Image capture(Using V4L)

We added one more camera to the system, which is causing the mess currently.
3.  Video capture (Using Motion)


  We notice either a video capture or image capture does not work in the system. various forums, suggested for adding quirk=128 in conf, even that idd not work out.
```

dmesg:

[  399.544408] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (1871:2097)

[  399.544429] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.

[  399.544441] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.

[  399.547449] input: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input32

[  399.668599] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (1871:0501)

[  399.668613] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.

[  399.668618] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.

[  399.671360] input: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4:1.0/input/input33
[  399.732317] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (1871:0f01)

[  399.732328] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.

[  399.732334] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.

[  399.735996] input: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input34

Tried getting V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE information for the cameera: all connected cameras listed  (YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV))

HW Spec:
    N2600
    Aveo technologies camera 3 models with diff VID:PID

I need some guidance in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finding:

**N2600 with 3.16 kernel :(Both with / without Quirk 0x80)**

> Bandwidth per camera was 328 Mb. In my case overall allocated
>   bandwidth was 656 (For 2 cameras) and max bandwidth for USB controller
>   was 800. So there was no space available for my third camera.

**N2600 with 2.6.32 kernel**

> Same my third camera did not work and memory allocation per camera was
>   320 Mb

**N2600 with 2.6.32 kernel with Quirk 0x80**

> On applying quirk to uvcvideo memory allocation was drastically
>   reduced from 320 to 128 Mb and all 3 cameras worked as expected.

**Solution**:

I am not very sure this a very correct solution. However, I would like to thank [Stuart (SwDevRefugee)](https://superuser.com/users/537966/swdevrefugee) for helping me troubleshoot and giving some pointers to address this issue.

There is this line in uvc_fixup_video_ctrl() in the newer kernel **bandwidth = max_t(u32, bandwidth, 1024);** and missing in old one. Commented and recompiled my UVC driver and now with **quirk 0x80** memory allocation has come down to 128 Mb from 328 and my system works. Rhough this might be helpful to someone with multiple cameras